# EditText with only numbers,comma,dot

Tags: android, xamarin

I have been create an edittext in my xml file.HEre is my code:

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/IpAdress"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789.," />
```

The problem is that in my output project it will work only one of the. Only dot or only comma. What is wrong ? In simulator works fine, only in my release doesnt.

Comment: To be dynamic to your rule, simple add a text listener to the edit text and when the new character is breaking your rule, simply set it to substring(0, length -1) etc

Comment: Who will i do this?Should i add something in my class?

Comment: Share your current implementation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484055/how-to-validated-fields-in-an-xamarin-android-app/38485853#38485853

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with different android : inputType.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/IpAdress"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:inputType="number"
android:digits="0123456789.-,+" />
```

It works

Answer (score -1):

You may add a textChangedListener to the editText

```
<editText variable>.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int count, int after) {
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
    int before, int count) {
         String s = <editText variable>.getText().toString();
         if(/*your rules here*/)
             /* modify your string s*/;
         <editText variable>.setText(s);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm using visualstudio 2015 with xamarin and c#. Where should i use this?

Comment: @DiH You can still add a TextChange event listener https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/controls/edittext/capture_user_input_text/

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: I have two empy box in my numperpad left and right from 0.

Comment: I'm 90% sure that my problem is android:inputType="numberDecimal"

Comment: You may try
android:inputType="text"
android:digits="0123456789.,"